# Logcat error when dynamically add custom views to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

I'm receiving such error in logcat when adding custom TextViews to RelativeLayout:

> "E/ThemeUtils: View class
> TableCircleCustomView is
> an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme
> (or descendant)."

My app theme is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Here is my custom view class:

```
class TableCircleCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    ....
}
```

Then in Fragment i'm adding this object to RelativeLayout like so

```
val viewItem = TableCircleCustomView(context)     
with(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(objectWidth, objectHeight)) {
  leftMargin = objectPosX
  topMargin = objectPosY
    
  binding.restaurantMap.addView(viewItem, this);
}
```

It's clear that i should set theme for some element, but i have no idea for which.
Can somebody help?